# Unity/Caliburn Micro, Injection Constructor with multiple parameters

Tags: mvvm, unity-container, caliburn.micro, constructor-injection

I am currently trying to learn how to implement MVVM using Unity and Caliburn Micro. After looking around for help elsewhere I am still unsure about how to set up the Constructor Injection properly. I don't know if this is not working due to my lack of expertise in MVVM or something else.

My problem is I want to pass in two IScreen Objects into my main window(shell) Class that can be navigated between when the user clicks on a button. Here is the code for the constructor in my MainWindowViewModel class:

```
private IScreen campaignViewModel, stringsViewModel;
public MainWindowViewModel(IScreen campaignViewModel, IScreen stringsViewModel)
{
    this.campaignViewModel = campaignViewModel;
    this.stringsViewModel = stringsViewModel;
    ActiveItem = this.campaignViewModel;
}
```

This is the code I am using in my Bootstrapper(Unity) class:

```
    private static IUnityContainer BuildContainer()
    {
        IUnityContainer result = new UnityContainer();
        result
            .RegisterInstance(result)
            .RegisterInstance<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager())
            .RegisterInstance<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());

        result
            .RegisterType<IScreen, CampaignsViewModel>()
            .RegisterType<IScreen, StringsViewModel>()
            .RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IScreen), typeof(IScreen)));

        return result;
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        var result = unity.Resolve(service, key);

        if (result == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instance of contract {0}", service));
        return result;
    }
```

When this runs the MainWindowViewModel receives two instances of StringsViewModel. Although if I were to put a key into the statement:

```
result.RegisterType<IScreen, StringsViewModel>("StringsView");
```

Then it passes in two instances of CampaignsViewModel. I don't know how to specify to the InjectionConstructor that I want it to pass in one instance of CampaignViewModel and StringsViewModel. I have a feeling it may have something to do with the GetInstance method, but I am unsure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you define the same interface twice.

How will the DI framework know which is which?? Answer: it can't.

> So instead of this use 2 interfaces:

```
 public MainWindowViewModel(ICampaignScreen campaignViewModel, IStringsScreen stringsViewModel)
```

You can make both of these inherit from IScreen:

```
 public interface ICampaignScreen : IScreen
```

and neither need add anything to IScreen - they simply provide a means for the Framework to differentiate between them.

Comment: Well, I just changed the injection to:
new InjectionConstructor(typeof(CampaignsViewModel),typeof(StringsViewModel)) and that has done it. I tried your method of creating Interfaces for each of the view models but I could not get it to compile. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Looking back at your answer I realise that you were infact correct and even though what I done worked, it was more of a hack than actually getting unity to resolve the interface. Creating an interface that derives from IScreen for each of the View models was the correct move. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Changed:

```
 result
            .RegisterType<IScreen, CampaignsViewModel>()
            .RegisterType<IScreen, StringsViewModel>()
            .RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IScreen), typeof(IScreen)));
```

To:

```
 result
            .RegisterType<IScreen, CampaignsViewModel>()
            .RegisterType<IScreen, StringsViewModel>()
            .RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(CampaignsViewModel), typeof(StringsViewModel)));
```

And this worked. I don't know if it violates any rules or principles but it works for now.