# DI, registering multiple instances for one interface definition

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have an interface `INavigationService` and a simple container that allows registration with and without key.

This is useful to me as the framework will inject the registered instances into the constructor of my view models.

Now I have multiple navigation services (due to frames in my UI). They all implement the same basic interface (`INavigationService`).

I want to be able to have the container inject these instances into the correct navigation tree (frame + subsequent views/view models) without me having to pass around parameters  (DI registration key).

How is this usually done?

I can imagine something that is attribute based (thus putting the registration key onto all dependent class definitions). But the container doesn't support this. It also seems to be a hassle.

I could also create an interface exclusively for tagging. So `INavigationService<T>` and register each navigation service with a different type argument. E.g. the type of the first view of a frame. This would give me the resolution I need, although I would pass around interfaces that do not have any meaning.

On the other hand, I get IDE support for finding dependent views (for example by creating types like `FileTreeNavigation : INavigationService<FileTreeView>`

Is there another pattern?

Comment: what DI library are you using?

Comment: @w0lf: The container is part of Caliburn.Micro (http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3cc9a20b8554#src%2fCaliburn.Micro.WP71.Extensions%2fSimpleContainer.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this applies to Caliburn Micro, but since the question is about patterns, I'll describe here the way I managed to solve this problem with [StrucureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/): using the `Ctor<>` method which allows specifying concrete types for constructor parameter resolution.

Also, I think using specialized interfaces (your `FileTreeNavigation` example) is great, but if for some reason you don't find this appropriate, read on.

Let's suppose that we have the `INavigationService` interface and two different implementations:

```
public interface INavigationService { }
public class NavigationServiceA : INavigationService { }
public class NavigationServiceB : INavigationService { }
```

Next, we have two different Service classes, both depending on the `INavigationService` interface:

```
public class ServiceA
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public ServiceA(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
}

public class ServiceB
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public ServiceB(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

Finally, we have a class that we'll resolve using the IoC container. The class depends on both `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` and is defined as follows:

```
public class SomeClassToResolve
{
    private readonly ServiceA _serviceA;
    private readonly ServiceB _serviceB;

    public SomeClassToResolve(ServiceA serviceA, ServiceB serviceB)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;
        _serviceB = serviceB;
    }
}
```

StructureMap offers the possibility of specifying what type to use in order to resolve a constructor parameter. This is how the registration looks like:

```
ForConcreteType<ServiceA>().Configure.Ctor<INavigationService>().Is<NavigationServiceA>();
ForConcreteType<ServiceB>().Configure.Ctor<INavigationService>().Is<NavigationServiceB>();
```

Now, when I call `container.GetInstance<SomeClassToResolve>();` it'll construct an instance of `SomeClassToResolve`, which has instances of `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` correctly constructed (having `NavigationServiceA` and `NavigationServiceB`, respectively).

This is one way to do it, that I found to be more straight forward. There's also the possibility of doing [Conditional Construction](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/19/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas/), but I think that can get pretty complex.

**PS:** searching for *"caliburn micro constructor"* I stumbled upon [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6570374/390819) which seems similar to what I'm doing with StructureMap (only that here it's called `InjectionConstructor`).

Comment: Just for info - the example mentioned in your PS is using DI tooling different from the built-in one - namely the Microsoft Unity library

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I will consider StructureMap when choosing a more complete DI solution. I am working on the WinRT platform, so StructureMap is not viable atm. Very good to know about this kind of feature, though. I think, I like the interface solution more for my immediate problem, since the differentiation stems from a real difference in dependency. The `INavigationService`s are in fact not interchangeable since they control a whole different navigation space - better to make the interface types incompatible. But I can see other uses of your suggestion. I like it. Thanks

Comment: @skarmats Sorry - I wasn't aware of that (the `InjectionConstructor` thing). Yes, I think separating the interfaces is the best approach.