# MVVM Light Apuntas Notas CategoryEditorViewModel constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, light

I have downloaded and run the example and understand most everything except I can't figure out where the CategoryEditorViewModel class gets it's constructor argument from.  It is "ICategoryRepository categoryRepository" and I've searched for references but still cannot understand how and where the paremeter gets passed when the viewmodel is created.
I'm hoping someone will help me with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same question.

As far as what I've figured out from threads like

[Constructors with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570109/unity-caliburn-micro-injection-constructor-with-multiple-parameters)

and lots more is that in the Apuntas Notas Project in the bootstrap.cs file , the interface ICategoryRepository is registered with the class CategoryReporitory.

Hence when the property `CategoryEditor` tries to resolve an instance in ViewModelLocator.cs via

```
        public CategoryEditorViewModel CategoryEditor
    {
        get { return _bootStrapper.Container.Resolve<CategoryEditorViewModel>(); }
    }
```

and an instance does not exist, it tries to create an object of that class `CategoryEditorViewModel` with its only constructor which expects the `ICategoryRespository` interface.

As I mentioned before, We have this interface registered in the bootstrap.cs file with `CategoryRepository` class. Hence it creates an object of CategoryRepository and passes that to the view-model constructor.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Oh and if you wonder what happens if you have multiple constructors, you can register one which you prefer by registering in bootstrap.cs with something like

```
Container.RegisterType<CategoryEditorViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ICategoryRepository), 5));
```

and now if you have another constructor in CategoryEditorViewModel additionally expecting an int, that will be called instead of the one that was there before. (passing an int value of 5 there is pretty stupid, but hope you get the picture, you can give the types of the parameters for your preferred constructor there and make sure they are registered with the bootstrap container too)